# Error to connect sql procedure with Visual studio on search

Tags: c#, sql-server, search

I just want to make the search bar, I have done that with webservice but now I stuck in one place. I am getting an error

> Procedure or function 'getTable' expects parameter '@term', which was
>   not supplied.

And the cs code is:

```
public void getB2bData(string term)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        //Search
        using (SqlCommand cmdSearch = new SqlCommand("dbo.getTable", con))
        {
            cmdSearch.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
            {
                cmdSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@search",term));
            }
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmdSearch.ExecuteReader();
            gvSearchNames.DataSource = rdr;
            gvSearchNames.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    getB2bData(txtName.Text); 
}
```

Comment: What is dbo.getTable? The error says you it's sp or function and it needs parameter that you did not supply. It won't work until you provide this parameter

Answer (score 1):

`getTable` expects `@term`, and you pass `@search` parameter.

Change:

```
cmdSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@search", term));
```

To:

```
cmdSearch.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@term", term));
```

Comment: You may wish to give the poster some advice about what to do if `term` is `null` or empty (since the code likely won't work in that scenario).